# How are the spanning vectors and null space of a matrix related?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say we have a matrix $A$.

From what I understand, the null space of A is the set of all vectors $v$, such that $A * v = 0$.

Also from my understanding, the spanning vectors of A are all the solutions to the homogeneous system that A represents. Is the span of the spanning vectors of A the null space of A?

I do believe there is a relationship somewhere I just don't see it.

Thank you.

Comment: I have never heard the term 'spanning vectors' used for the null space. (Then again, I haven't heard of many things...)

Comment: Which textbook are you using?  That might help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

I quite  don't get the notion of spanning vectors of A. For me a matrix is a linear transformation from $V \to W$ where V is a vector space of dimension n , W is of m( when the matrix is $ n \times m $ )

Now we have a set of vectors $ v_1,,v_n ;w_1,w_2..w_m$  basis for V and W.
Now the null space(kernel) is spanned by some set of $v_i$'s and the image is spanned by some set of $w_i$'s The rank-nullity theorem states that $\dim(\ker A) + \dim( im(A))  = n $. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I'm currently in my first course of linear algebra, I've been reading the book quite a bit but I still don't quite understand what you are telling me. I have some more reading to do!

Comment: read the rank nullity theorem in your book . After you reach there , you shall have a better idea of this